# In Word 2013 do I need Section Breaks before and after section?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using Word 2013 in a Windows computer.

When I creating Section Break (Continuous), do I  need to nest the section between a Section Break (Continuous) #1 and Section Break (Continuous) #2 ?

Or, do I just create one Section Break (Continuous) section for each section at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one section break at the start of each section, except the first section, which needs no section break. The layout of you document should look like this:

> Contents
>
> [Section break]
>
> Contents
>
> [Section break]
>
> Contents
>
> ...

Section breaks in Microsoft Word create a new section after themselves. These sections inherit the pagination settings of the previous section but let you change them without affecting the previous section.